# using network-bootstrapper to generate node-info expects certificates with devMode=false

Tags: corda

I am trying to use network-bootstrapper tool to generate node-infos(like certificates etc) by passing node.conf file as input with devMode=false, following is my node.conf file:

```
myLegalName="O=Bank,L=Paris,C=FR"
p2pAddress="localhost:10011"
devMode=false
rpcSettings {
    address="localhost:10012"
    adminAddress="localhost:10052"
}
security {
    authService {
        dataSource {
            type=INMEMORY
            users=[
                {
                    password=test
                    permissions=[
                        ALL
                    ]
                    user=user3
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I am passing the path of node.conf file as an argument to the bootsrapper.jar, but it is exiting with error code 1, below is the screenshot of the error:
[image]

following is the log generated:

```
[INFO ] 2018-07-04T14:19:21,901Z [main] internal.Node.generateAndSaveNodeInfo - Generating nodeInfo ... {}
[ERROR] 2018-07-04T14:19:21,901Z [main] internal.Node.validateKeystore - IO         exception while trying to validate keystore {}
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\corda\work\keys-    gen\Bank\certificates\sslkeystore.jks
......
......
```

And

```
[ERROR] 2018-07-04T14:19:21,917Z [main] internal.Node.run - Exception during     node startup {}
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Identity certificate not found. Please     either copy your existing identity key and certificate from another node, or if     you don't have one yet, fill out the config file and run corda.jar --initial-    registration. Read more at: https://docs.corda.net/permissioning.html
......
......
```

Can you please let me know how to generate certificates and place it already inside the folder `{workspace}/{nodeName}/certificates` which already does not exists and is being generated by the bootstrapper tool itself? can you help with certificate generation and usage of network-bootstrapper.jar tool with devMode turned off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bootstrapper tool can't be used outside of `devMode`. Outside of `devMode`, proper certificates and a network map server must be used.

This issue is being tracked here: https://r3-cev.atlassian.net/browse/CORDA-1735.