# upgrade CordaApp for production deployment

Tags: corda, production

I'm working on a little CordApp following the [cordapp-example](https://github.com/corda/samples/tree/release-V4/cordapp-example)

When I'm starting the node, a red message appears in the corda-node shell indicating that the node is running in development mode.
From what I've read [here](https://docs.corda.net/corda-configuration-file.html), I have to set `devMode=false` in every `node.conf` and implements all necessary certificates for every node.

https://docs.corda.net/permissioning.html and https://docs.corda.net/permissioning.html

Could someone help me with these problems?

- How to proceed to add certificates and set devMode = false? it would be great to have a tutorial / guide with the steps to perform to generate all the certificates
- What other steps are required for production deployment for my CordApp?
- How can I expose the API built by the client module (always taking the cordapp-example project as an example) mapped on the MainController.kt with https protocol?

I appreciate every help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I assume you've got all the keystore and truststore files at hand.

- nothing special to do, just

  - set devMode as false
  - put all the keystore and truststore in certificates/ folder
  - config your node.conf to add doorman URL and networm map URL
- there is no official guide about how to deploy your CorDapp in production because it heavily depends on your business: how many Jar files, customised config items, DB schema, etc. Basically, just do what you've done in development environment, nothing special. However, here is an overall guide on CorDapp development, hope it'd help:
  https://docs.corda.net/cordapp-build-systems.html
- I don't quite get your question, do you mean: how can MainController expose HTTPS so that other application (like postman, or Javascript application) can consume, right? If this is the case, in fact, MainController.kt is a Spring Boot controller who exposes REST API to public, you'd access it anywhere as long as you've deployed the fat Jar file (generated from samples/cordapp-example/clients/ project) and run it as a service.

FYI, the node.conf file should finally like this:

```
networkServices {
    doormanURL="http://localhost:10000"
    networkMapURL="http://localhost:20000"
}
devMode = false
```

Please also refer to these topics:

[using network-bootstrapper to generate node-info expects certificates with devMode=false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51184021)

https://www.edureka.co/community/1068/how-do-i-generate-corda-nodes-keystores-in-dev-mode